# Automate reading users from config file and apply a math function to the read users

Tags: python, csv, parsing, logic

how would I:

1. Automate reading in all users in row[0] of a config file csv and store those users
2. Then, run them all through a math function that will output different values for each of them

To format of the csv's are the same: (DEREK,23, 12.344444444, 5)
Output expected:  143.34

Right now, I have user interaction with finding all the users but this needs to be changed to have a faster program.

```
with open("main.csv") as input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        data.append((row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2]))) #row[0] being strings aka the users the rest are their values

with open("user_dat.csv") as usr_in:
    for rows in csv.reader(usr_in):
        usr_dat.append((rows[0], int(rows[1]), int(rows[2]), int(rows[3])))

with open("all_user_values.csv", 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for usrs, val, val1 in usr_dat: # problem lies here because i have no idea how to go about doing this
        for usr, chng, cst in data:

        if act_name in usrs:
             if name in usr:
                do(stuff)
```

Comment: I still have not clue what you are trying to write in the 'all_user_values.csv'  file. Give an example of how the other 2 files are and what output is expected for it in the resulting file.

Comment: main.csv = main dataset with multiple users and values associated with them user_dat.csv = user set with all the users too  look for all_user_values.csv is where all the users and values that are summed from main.csv + user_dat.csv are stored 

To format the csv's are the same: (DEREK,23, 12.344444444)
Output expected: <user> 143.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make things clear.
You have two separate lists.
Each list holds three items per "user" - name, and two int values.

You can iterate over each list (or a list that contains the two lists, is even better), and call "do" on each item in the lists (item is all three values as a tuple, like so:

```
validated_names = ['name1', 'name2']
final_list = data + usr_dat  # Both lists combined into one
for user_tuple in final_list:
    do_stuff(user_tuple)

def do_stuff(user_tuple):
    name, int_values_tuple = user_tuple
    if name in validated_names:
        do_other_stuff(int_values_tuple)

def do_other_stuff(packed_values):
    if len(packed_values) == 2:
       calc_two_ints(packed_values)
    elif len(packed_values) == 3:
       calc_three_ints(packed_values)
    else:
       pass  # No such cases for now.

def calc_two_ints(packed_values):
    val1, val2 = packed_values
    # Do something

def calc_three_ints(packed_values):
    val1, val2, val3 = packed_values
    # Do something
```

Comment: Yes you are correct i forgot to mention that some users have 3 values

Comment: There are like 12 users and more will be added so i need to iterate throught the config file till i reach EOF

Comment: Is there a way to just do the checking if the <user1> is in both datasets without putting it into list just read and compare?

Comment: You could call "do_stuff" function directly from your "with open" code block, without keeping the users in a list, and re-iterating over them again.